# Travelling to the US with codeine-based medicines

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, health

I'm travelling to the US next month, and I'd like to take my codeine-based painkillers with me. In the UK these are available without a prescription, [over the counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over-the-counter_drug#United_Kingdom) from a pharmacist. (It isn't just available in any old supermarket like some painkillers, but can just be sold in a pharmacy under supervision from the pharmacist, no Doctor involved)

I see from [this CBP advice](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/67/kw/prescription%20medicine) that *prescription* medication must have a prescription label attached, but presumably this applies to medicines that are only available on prescription in the US.  So my question is twofold:

- Can I bring my codeine-based painkillers to the US without a prescription?
- More generally, is there a list of medicines that are commonly available in other parts of the world but restricted in the US?

Comment: I thing problem here isn't whether it's prescription drug or not, but the fact that codeine is narcotic, and as such by the [Controlled Substances Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_Substances_Act), your pills are most likely considered [Schedule III drugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_Substances_Act#Schedule_III_controlled_substances)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really would rather be safe than sorry, you should follow the advice on the page you linked to, as it is advice I've followed in the past:

**A valid prescription or doctors note is required on all medication entering the U.S.**

Now practically we all know that's not really the case.  Bringing in paracetamol/tylenol, or Imodium, or asthma medicines, etc, are generally waved right through.  However many countries, including the U.S. as documented, technically require that documentation for **all** medicines so they have recourse for suspicious circumstances.

In the case of any medicines you're not sure about, it's definitely worth obtaining a doctor's note - it doesn't have to be a prescription, as a letter from your doctor should suffice.  If you really must bring in your codeine-based medicines, it seems like a simple and sensible step to take.

The CBP give similar and more extensive advice on [another page](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/kbyg/prohibited-restricted), which would presumably cover codeine under "potentially addictive drugs/narcotics":

> If you need medicines that contain potentially addictive drugs or
> narcotics (e.g., some cough medicines, tranquilizers, sleeping pills,
> antidepressants or stimulants), do the following:
>
> - Declare all drugs,
>   medicinals, and similar products to the appropriate CBP official;
> - Carry such substances in their original containers;
> - Carry only the
>   quantity of such substances that a person with that condition (e.g.,
>   chronic pain) would normally carry for his/her personal use; and
> - **Carry a prescription or written statement from your physician that
>   the substances are being used under a doctor's supervision and that
>   they are necessary for your physical well being while traveling.**

Comment: Thanks, that's good advice -- on reflection I think I'll leave the codeine at home rather than waste my GP's time, and just take more normal painkillers.  Or just buy some when I get there :)

Comment: @Flup I don't think codeine is available in the US without a prescription so you probably wouldn't be able to buy it while there.

Answer (score 4):

Tylenol with codeine can be brought into the USA without a prescription.  The catch is you can only bring in the bottle with 50 pills.  You can't bring in the 100 or 159 pill quantity.

How do I know?  I brought in a bottle with 100 once and the CBP officer said we could only bring in the 50 quantity bottles.